# Int array iteration?

Tags: java, arrays, int, iteration

My main goal is to iterate from a defined start location in an array to the end of the array to find the index of the minimum value then swap it with the index zero, iterating through will keep swapping it to 1 index higher than the previous . I have a method that finds the minimum of the array and a method at my attempt to obtain the index of the min value. Here is what I have:

```
   static int min(int[] parameter){
       int minValue = 101;
       for(int z = 0 ; z<parameter.length; z++){
           if(parameter[z] < minValue){
           minValue = parameter[z];
           }
       }
       return minValue;
    }

    static int locateMin (int start, int[] array) {
        int n = 0;
        int value = array[n]; 
        int location = 0;
        for (n= start; n < array.length; n++) {
            if (array[n] < value){ 
                value = array[n];
                location = n;
            }
        }
        return location;

    }
    static void swap(int[] arr, int locationOne, int locationTwo){
        int pos = arr[locationOne];
        arr[locationOne] = arr[locationTwo];
        arr[locationTwo] = pos;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] array = generateArray(10);
        showArray(array);
        swap(array, 0, locateMin(0, array));
        swap(array, 1, locateMin(1, array));
        swap(array, 2, locateMin(2, array));
        showArray(array);
   }
```

My problem is that it doesn't place the values in the correct index, and iterates incorrectly. Any ideas as to why? Furthermore, my current output shows:

```
63 10 47 94 89 68 15 12 27 42 
10 10 10 94 89 68 15 12 27 42
```

Comment: consider adding sample input and output expected. It will drastically saves time to understand your goal

Comment: for example, if array is  [ 12 6 7 45 54 69 23 1 0 23] then after swapping three times it should be [ 0 1 6 45 54 69 23 7 12 23]

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] array = generateArray(10);
        showArray(array);
        swap(array, 0, locateMin(0, array));
        swap(array, 1, locateMin(1, array));
        swap(array, 2, locateMin(2, array));
        showArray(array);
   }
```

This is hardcoded and can produce many errors if not careful. I suggest iterating through this to switch. Also, you seem to be doing a Selection Sort.

Your min function does not seem to be used anywhere either.

EDIT:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int minValIndex(int start, T array[]) {
    int minIndex = start;

    for (int cLoc = start; cLoc < array.length; cLoc++) {
        minIndex = (array[cLoc].compareTo(array[minIndex]) < 0) ? cLoc : 
                minIndex;
    }

    return minIndex;
}

public static <T> void swap(T array[], int loc1, int loc2) {
    T temp = array[loc1];
    array[loc1] = array[loc2];
    array[loc2] = temp;
}
```

These methods are used to find the minIndex and swap two indexes. You can use these two methods. In your main method you need to first generate an array, and then loop through the array as you were doing to sort it.

Comment: Yes after getting my swap and locateMin methods down, i will implement a selection sort method, right now it will give me a faulty outcome. So should I use my min method inside my locateMin to make it iterate easier? the min method was provided because i thought the other methods will make use of it but I have not found a way yet.

Comment: If you're not implementing the full selection sort, then there is no way the array will be fully sorted. The only way to tell is fully write the sort then test it. You can easily test your min() method without having to sort. You should also be able to test your swap without sorting it.

I may be misunderstanding what you are asking.

Comment: the idea is to get the the methods to work coherently so that I can sort the values without implementing a selection sort first.

Comment: I listed two methods. If you cannot figure it out from there i can also write a main method to demonstrate how to use these methods and such.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I can see is in your locateMin function when the element its checking is already the minimum.

```
static int locateMin (int start, int[] array) {
    int n = 0;
    int value = array[n]; 
    int location = 0; //Location is set to 0
    for (n= start; n < array.length; n++) {
        if (array[n] < value){ //There are no values smaller than it.
            value = array[n];
            location = n;
        }
    }
    return location; //returns 0

}
```

You should set n to start, and also use that as the value for location.

```
    int n = start;
    //...
    int location = n;
```

Answer (score 0):

You were setting `n = 0` in `locateMin(...)` and so you were setting `int value = array[n];`
i.e. `value = array[0]` , which means you are initially setting 1st value of array to be minimum value and using it to compare further.
Just replace following :

```
int n = 0;
int value = array[n]; 
int location = 0;
```

from `locateMin(...)` with this :

```
int n = array.length - 1;
int value = array[n];
int location = n;
```